# Sending email with standard event Invites email content to contact through apex class

Tags: email-template

Currently our sales reps using Lightning experience for sales cycle feature but Add Invites feature is not available on event page, moreover email is not sending to customer whenever sales rep is created event activity to contact record. So that, i am planning to build custom apex class for sending email with standard event page (please see below screenshot.) to contact whenever event record is created by sales rep.

[image]